# SQL query Optimisation JOIN multiple column

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, optimization, ms-access-2010

I have two tables on Microsoft Access: T_DATAS (about 200 000 rows) and T_REAF (about 1000 rows).

T_DATAS has a lot of columns (about 30 columns) and T_REAF has about 10 columns.

I have to tell you that I am not allowed to change those tables nor to create other tables. I have to work with it.

Both tables have 6 columns that are the same. I need to join the tables on these 6 columns, to select ALL the columns from T_DATAS AND the columns that are in T_REAF but not in T_DATAS.

My query is :

`SELECT A.*, B.CARROS_NEW, B.SEGT_NEW, B.ATTR
INTO FINALTABLE
FROM T_DATAS A LEFT JOIN T_REAF B ON
                      A.REGION LIKE B.REGION AND
                      A.PAYS LIKE B.PAYS AND
                      A.MARQUE LIKE B.MARQUE AND
                      A.MODELE LIKE B.MODELE AND
                      A.CARROS LIKE B.CARROS AND
                      A.SEGT LIKE B.SEGT`

I have the result I need but the problem is that this query is taking way too long to give the result (about 3 minutes). 
I know that T_DATAS contains a lot of rows (200 000) but I think that 3 minutes is too long for this query.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this query?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: why are you using **like** over here in query?

Comment: Also, consider putting some indexes over tables to speed up query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps for this.  One is changing the query to use `=`.  I'm not 100% sure if this is necessary, but it can't hurt.  The second is to create an index.

So:

```
SELECT D.*, R.CARROS_NEW, R.SEGT_NEW, R.ATTR
INTO FINALTABLE
FROM T_DATAS D LEFT JOIN
     T_REAF R
     ON D.REGION = R.REGION AND
        D.PAYS = R.PAYS AND
        D.MARQUE = R.MARQUE AND
        D.MODELE = R.MODELE AND
        D.CARROS = R.CARROS AND
        D.SEGT = R.SEGT;
```

Second, you want an index on `T_REAF`:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_REAF_6 ON T_REAF(REGION, PAYS, MARQUE, MODELE, CARROS, SEGT);
```

MS Access can then use the index for the `JOIN`, speeding the query.

Note that I changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names.  This makes it easier to follow the logic in the query.

Comment: Thanks! Changing from "LIKE" to "AND" made the request faster (about 30 seconds against 3mins before). I also created the index. Is there a way to see if the index is really used by Access or do I have to "trust" it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that those 6 columns are same may have same datatype also.

**Note:** Equals (=) operator is a comparison operator - that compares two values for equality. So in your query replace `LIKE` with `=` and see the result time.

```
SELECT A.*
      ,B.CARROS_NEW
      ,B.SEGT_NEW
      ,B.ATTR
       INTO FINALTABLE
FROM   T_DATAS A
       LEFT JOIN T_REAF B
            ON  A.REGION = B.REGION
                AND A.PAYS = B.PAYS
                AND A.MARQUE = B.MARQUE
                AND A.MODELE = B.MODELE
                AND A.CARROS = B.CARROS
                AND A.SEGT = B.SEGT
```